# Mobile version of profile page showing "1 votes"

Tags: bug, profile-page, mobile-web, plurals

"1 votes" is shown in user profile on mobile site:

[image: votes]

I know there is a workaround: vote more. But still.

Comment: That one additional test case could cascade into a catastrophic failure of the system.  Then what will we do?  More outages?  Tweets with typos?

Comment: @lostsock no it's not. We should not close every pluralization bug as dupe of that one. As balpha says in the answer there, those **are** bugs.

Comment: @jonsca really? So you thinks the site shoulds contained broked English?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Only Stack Overlfow.

Comment: @Sha (to your first comment) It is a joke :D

Comment: @nicael sorry but closing a question as a joke is not funny.

Comment: @Sha it won't be closed because of one-two votes.

Comment: @nicael it might. Please don't abuse the moderation powers, it's enough we sometimes close valid questions as site specific, if we'll start closing just "for fun" the team will simply nuke our powers here on MSE. So stop doing it.

Comment: @lostsock thanks, they do fix those but like balpha said it's low priority.

Comment: @lostsock To dispel that impression, compare the results of searches for [answers:200](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A200) and [answers:300](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A300) on this site. "2 results", "1 result".