# "This question has received 1 upvotes and 2 downvotes"

Tags: bug, status-completed, tooltips, vote-count, plurals

When expanding the votes count and hovering over it, there is a tooltip with details:

[image: tooltip with plurals bug]

The grammar in the above example is wrong:

> This question has received 1 upvote**s** and 2 downvotes

Can you please fix the grammar in the tooltip text?

Comment: [Related discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165619/are-reports-of-pluralisation-bugs-welcome).

Comment: Now I can't find the question, but I think this might be a duplicate.

Comment: @LemmyX I wouldn't be at all surprised, but I couldn't find it either.

Comment: Me neither, although there's [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348378/269301) about close votes. And [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/241906/269301) very old report from mobile.

Comment: I don't see anything related to the question in the screenshot. Where you see that text? Also, I don't like your tone which is arrogant and not friendly towards SE developers. -2 if I could.

Comment: @Shadow see the image of the tooltip. (FWIW, the question seems innocuous to me, not like it’s aimed against the SE devs. Maybe if you read the question as rhetorical, then it will appear rude.)

Comment: @Shadow The question was not intended to be sarcastic. I realize that it might be difficult to fix this and wanted to know if that were the case.

Comment: @Matt "Is it difficult to use correct grammar", for me at least, came as "You have wrong grammar, and since it's easy to fix it's a stupid bug". I mean, of course it's not "difficult", so why sting? Anyway, someone else changed it, and I made the report itself more clear. All good now.

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance Not having punctuation in alt text causes run on sentences for screen readers. (I'd also argue that you don't needed the alt text at all now that you've added the transcription of the relevant text.)

Comment: @BSMP not sure what you mean. Alt text should be a short description what the image is about, not whole paragraph. Anyway, feel free to edit the post.

Answer (score 8):

Even though there's no official response, I'm answering because it seems this has been fixed:
[image]

Thanks!